# Stored procedure returns wrong values with jdbc driver

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, jtds

I'm having a strange situation on a Stored Procedure on my MSSQL Server when executed via a jdbc driver. I have tried jtds and microsoft jdbc with the same results.

I have other SPs that work perfectly but on this one, there is a strange situation.

Here is the content of the SP:

```
select b.columnA, count(b.columnA) as Rejects
   into #TempTable
   from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.columnA = b.columnA
   where b.columnB is null
   and a.columnC = 1
   group by b.columnA
   having count(b.columnA) > 2;

   declare @count int
   set @count = 99 --(select count(columnA) as Count from #TempTable)

   select @count as Total, a.columnD
   from (
   select count(a.columnA) as columnD
   from #TempTable a inner join tableA b on a.columnA = b.columnA
   where a.Rejects = 3
   and registerDate>=dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) ) a
```

The problem here is on the set @count.

If I use a forced value, such as 99, it works correctly. If, instead of using the forced value I use the commented select with the count from the temp table, it works great on MSMSM but, if executed via JDBC (I used two different clients with both jtds and microsoft jdbc driver) the final "Total" value is wrong. 
On some executions, the value even changes.

The execution method is the same both on MSMSM and JDBC clients: exec SP_Name;

What might be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

Update:

I've followed some suggestions and made a

```
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

To check the results. And, although the lines I got on the result set have the correct data, I don't have all the lines. Each time I run this SP I get different lines. This is why the results from the original SP are always a wrong number (lower than the supposed result) and sometimes vary.

Doing the same test on MSMSM, the result is always the same, with the same correct number of lines on the result set of the Temp Table.

Comment: Im not familiar with jdbc. But if you instead using a `#TempTable`  use a real table you get the correct count? My guess is the temporal table isnt being accesable.

Comment: Probably, but if the #TempTable were not accesable, wouldn't the result be empty for the last select? Because I do receive values, just not correct. For example, if the correct value is 100, i might receive 70.. Thanks

Comment: I just suggest you try. If `set  @count = 99 `  work check what is returning  the count from the #temp and a real table. If real table work but #table doesnt, you found the big. Also you can try `SELECT INTO @count   COUNT() ...`

Comment: I'm guessing the SQL above has been obfuscated, what count are you after? Rowcount? `count(columnA)` will be count of non-null values. What happens if you use `SELECT @count = count(columnA) from #TempTable`?

Comment: How "wrong"? Zero? Counts rows you don't want? Doesn't count some rows? Absolutely random number?

Comment: Thank you Juan. I did a select to the temp table and, although i get data and the data is correct, i don't get all the data. What I mean is that each line I get is correct, I'm just not getting all the lines that I am getting when selecting the same temp table on MSMSM. SELECT INTO @count did not work either. Thanks

Comment: Yes Rhys and Ivan, I'm counting the rows of the temp table. From another test, I did a `select * from #temp` and although the results are correct for each line I get, I don't get all the lines. The same select on MSMSM returned all the supposed lines. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved, @valter.vx?

Comment: @SqlZim no.. Had to do it via ODBC.. Never got it to work..